# Delete Fedora, install Ubuntu, keep Windows

Tags: system-installation

I installed fedora (version 17 beta) some time ago, but I don't like it. I'd like to replace it with ubuntu 13.10 and keep my Windows 7 untouched. I use GRUB to boot. My computer is 64-bit. I don't have the windows installation cd.

During ubuntu installation I don't know what to do with fedora partitions.
Can I delete them in windows? Won't that also delete grub? Will I be able to boot normally after that?
[partition view in windows](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79065269/fedora.jpg)

Comment: Since beta versions are never quite the same, I would recommend upgrading to Fedora 19 -  or wait for 20 which is apparently going to be released on Tuesday *(17th December 2013)*.

Comment: Fedora 20 is out now if you want to try it - http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be"

- Insert Ubuntu LiveDVD/USB.
- Begin with Ubuntu installation.
- When the option comes to choose the partition on which to install, delete the one with Fedora using the '-' button on bottom-left of the window.
- Now, select the free-space just created, click on '+' button to create a new 'ext4' partition.
- Continue.

P.S. Make sure you've backed up anything important you had on the Fedora partition beforehand.

Comment: Deleting other OS partitions from Windows is a good idea, as it then you don't remove bits of Windows without being warned beforehand...

Comment: @wilf I'm sorry, I fail to understand what you mean by that. I use Ubuntu 13.10 & Windows 7 (dual-boot) & have Ubuntu+Win7+(optional 3rd OS) since 2009. All distros are independent of each other; an issue can arise when a link (say fstab entry or GRUB entry) has been made which no longer exists but is accessed. If you were to simply 'delete' a *NIX partition from Windows, in fact, the GRUB may end up corrupted. The method I've suggested is something that I've been using for years now, and it has never caused an issue. Removing 'bits of Windows' is not even reqd. Please clarify, I may be wrong.

Comment: You not wrong @TomKat, but often it is far too easy to remove bits of Windows in Linux... You can restore GRUB with a Linux Live Disk, while not a Windows C drive... GRUB should be added back by Ubuntu, and would be different to the Fedora one *(slightly)*.

Comment: @wilf But, WHY would Windows even be affected if all he does is delete the 'Fedora' partition? He doesn't even HAVE to touch Windows. There's nothing that can go wrong unless he deliberately does that. On the other hand, breaking GRUB (I mean ending up w/o a Boot Manager) is a possibility if the Fedora partition is deleted from Windows (and MBR not installed). And even if MBR is no longer there, it can be installed by trying to install Win7 and finally choosing a simple 'Repair' option when old one is detected. I've done it.

Comment: @wilf 'GRUB should be added back by Ubuntu, and would be different to the Fedora one (slightly).' There would be NO difference in this case as there would be no Fedora when GRUB would be installed; and Ubuntu would place itself on top in the list. (If you implied difference in colour, I agree with you. :-) )

Comment: Dear @wilf, WHY would he even delete anything related to Windows anyway? WHY? :-/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to back up the stuff you want in F17b, wipe it in Windows disk manager *(then you don't remove any important Windows partitions)*, and then fill the space with Ubuntu in a normal dual boot.

Deleting the Fedora partitions can also be done from an Ubuntu Live disk - so in GParted or the install manager, select the ext* partitions and delete those - you can then fill the space with Ubuntu.:

[image] 
Windows is going to be on ntfs by default.

Guide [here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422) for removing Linux from Windows.

See [here](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony) for Dual-boot stuff.

Comment: Nice answer, wilf. However, I feel that 'Guide here for removing Linux from Windows' is fine when you wish to use Windows only after completely removing a *NIX distro. But, if you were simply replacing one distro with another (Fedora with Ubuntu), it's unnecessary work. If you simply try to install the replacement, and delete old distro's partition when the partition-selection shows up, it'd be fine as GRUB would be reinstalled, and all traces of old distros would be removed (keeping the Windows one safe). What's your opinion?

Comment: You can restore grub with a live disk - I'll find something and add it to my answer @TomKat - Also, Grub would be installed with Ubuntu anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: Restoring GRUB is not even required here, it'd be done when he installs Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: Exactly @TomKat, so deleting the partitions from Windows is fine :-)

Comment: Yes, it's fine as long as you're fine without a boot manager. (This too won't be an issue if he anyway has the Ubuntu Live USB/DVD ready in advance before deleting the partition through Windows, doing a lot of extra work he doesn't anyway have to do, and which is a way things might go wrong.) It's an unwritten rule: Never touch *NIX partitions from Windows, things may go out of hand.

Comment: Never touch Windows partitions from Linux, it *can* get out of hand. As they are being deleted, it should work anyway.

Comment: Actually, @wilf, I once made this mistake of deleting an Ubuntu boot partition from Windows and ended up w/o a boot-manager. (No MBR 'cos GRUB had erased it earlier, no GRUB 'cos the partition was gone!) And it was really a pain to after that. Since then, I've the way I've suggested.

Comment: So you don't think it will work. I think it could. Running the install of Ubuntu should sort it out. In response to your other comment @TomKat, it just could happen, as everyone makes mistakes. Sorry to have annoyed you :-)

Comment: I don't say it won't, I fear it may lead to what I had experienced. Let's hope for the best, else the community (and we for that matter) would have another Q coming. :-P

Goodnight (or whatever time it is where you are), @wilf. :-)

Comment: Good evening here., @TomKat . I would like it to be good night, Except I've got all this work to finish - doing this to pass the time...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start the Ubuntu install and then you can either A: just repartition the Fedora there to free disk space, or B: uninstall Fedora and overwrite it with Ubuntu.